# Unresolved reference:toUpperCase Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Im currently developing Kotlin in Android Studio 3.1
out of an JsonReader I receive an `String!`, which I'm trying to convert to upper case
so what i do is:

```
var name=reader.nextString().toUpperCase()
```

the problem is, that the `toUpperCase` is not detected and is marked as unresolved reference

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle` configurations for Kotlin? Is the rest of your project working?

Comment: The string u received, is it nullable? If yes, can you try                         
 var name=reader.nextString()?.toUpperCase()

Comment: Everything else is working fine.
no, the string is not nullable, that was my first thought too
@zsmb13

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

Comment: reader.nextString().capitalize();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`toUpperCase()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-upper-case.html) method is defined as an inline extension function to `String` not as a `java.lang.String`. Thus you need to have the *Kotlin* standard library as your dependency to use this method for `String`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Altough that worked to fix the unresolved reference, I'm not able to build my Project anymore, because this import is causing following error:

Program type already present: kotlin.AutoCloseableKt

Comment: You can have a look at how you handle the _Kotlin_ stdlib dependencies. Maybe you have more than one there. But this might be a different question you can ask. Just make sure to put all relevant files like the `build.gradle` as well.

Comment: could figure it out. it's a problem with a library I'm using

Comment: By the way, as stated in the link at the beginning of this answer, `toUpperCase()` is deprecated, now.

Answer (score -3):

capitalize Function can do the same as toUpperCase.

fun String.capitalize(): String

Returns a copy of this string having its first letter uppercased, or the original string, if it's empty or already starts with an upper case letter.

```
println("abcd".capitalize()) // Abcd
println("Abcd".capitalize()) // Abcd
```

For more details read the  [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/capitalize.html).

Comment: capitalize only does the first letter, but touppercase does all letters, so not the same thing